# Styling Geo Primitives

Tags: graphics, geography, style

How do you style the following:

```
GeoGraphics[{Red, Opacity[1], GeoDisk[{60, 20}]}, 
 GeoBackground -> None]
```

[image: Pink Image]

so that the resulting disk is exactly red? `GeoCircle` seems to work as expected, but not `GeoDisk` generates an underlying style with transparency, as does `GeoBoundsRegion`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`GeoStyling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoStyling.html):

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[Red], GeoDisk[{60, 20}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`GeoGraphics` uses a predefined opacity for `GeoDisk` primitives. Calling `Opacity` prior to the generation of the `GeoDisk` object will not change its value.

A possibility is to modify the opacity once the graphics is created:

```
graphics = GeoGraphics[{Red, GeoDisk[{60, 20}]}, GeoBackground -> None];

graphics /. Directive[Opacity[0.2`]] -> Directive[Opacity[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Excellent explanation, but such implementation is inconsistent both with overall design of `Graphics` and with the Docs for `GeoDisk` where we read under **Details and Options**: "`FaceForm`, `EdgeForm`, and `GeoStyling` can be used to specify how the interiors and boundaries of geographic regions should be rendered." I understand why they have implemented it this way but I still would call this a wrong design decision or a bug.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks. I agree, it would make sense and be consistent to be able to supersede the default opacity just by calling `Opacity`.

Comment: Your (apparently hackish) workaround can be simplified to ``graphics /. Directive[Opacity[0.2`]] -> {}``. The hackish nature of the solution is what makes me feeling that the design is wrong. They simply shouldn't include any hard-coded styling into basic primitives.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Ah yes, this is nicer. I would be concerned about having no default for the opacity of `GeoDisk`. It seems to be useful in the majority of cases, and the alternative of specifying each time the `Opacity` is perhaps not user-friendly. This being said, I agree it would be better not to "lock" this styling, and let the user be able to change it as for any other directive of any other primitive.

Comment: In GeoGraphics maps there are two sets of primitives: the geo primitives, that should be understood as "painted" on the surface of the Earth, and the primitives, that are "painted" on the projected map. The latter follow the rules of Graphics (including the default opacity 1), and the former follow the geo rules (including the default opacity 0.2 to avoid covering the background maps). Both sets respond in the same way to bare directives, except for opacity, because defaults are different. The GeoStyling wrapper explicitly affects only the geo primitives.